# React Native - Dynamically change component position

Tags: react-native, animation, layout, dynamic, position

I want to display several components (maybe up to 6) in my React Native app that continuously change their position, i.e. slowly but fluently float on the screen and change their moving direction randomly or based on an angle at which they approach the edge of their parent, if they do. What I don't know is how to change their position dynamically in a performance friendly way. Because I also want to let the user interact with them by tapping on them, it cannot be a video in a background or something similar.

If I were dealing with a standard React app running in a browser, I think I would simply manipulate the element's style attributes `top` and `left`. Since I want to implement this in React Native, I think there must be a solution that is way more performant and elegant, involving manipulation of the native elements that back the React Native views or using some animation mechanism, because re-rendering a view with like 6 components at least 30 times per second doesn't seem like an appropriate solution and an overhead in general.

Googling things like "react native dynamically move element" or "react native dynamically change element position" did not bring any obviously appropriate results. I came across a native element method `setNativeProps`, though, but couldn't find any information on what props I could set to change the element's position on the screen and how performant that would be. I also looked into React Native's `Animated` API, but could not quite relate my problem to the solutions that this API offers from a first glance.

Does anyone know a mechanism or maybe a library that would be appropriate to use in the situation that I described?

Comment: Why do you think the `Animated` api is not suitable for you? With that I believe you can animated their absolute position without re-rendering them

Comment: @Andus yes, I took a second look at that API and I believe I've found a solution. I'll post an answer when I implement it, if it works.